# StreamCorruptedException while deserializating object from ftp

Tags: java, serialization, ftp, deserialization

colleagues.
I am doing a university assessment and I need to implement FTP server communication. Serialization seem to work properly but deserialization doesn't.
The steps I make:

1. Retrieve FTP file stream to ByteArrayOutputStream
2. Close the stream
3. Write stream to byte array
4. Read byte array with ByteArrayInputStream wrapped into ObjectInputStream.

When I try to read object I get

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00.
```

Here's the code:

```
try {
        ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect("********",21);
        ftpClient.login("******", "******");
        ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(ftpClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        boolean ok = ftpClient.retrieveFile("/data/" + fileName,bos);
        System.out.println("" + ok + " " + ftpClient.getReplyCode());
        bos.close();
        byte[] b = bos.toByteArray();
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b));
        if (fileName.contains("dataW")) {
            Warrior character = (Warrior)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyCode());
            MainMenu frame = new MainMenu(character);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            parent.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            Rogue character = (Rogue)ois.readObject();
            MainMenu frame = new MainMenu(character);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            parent.setVisible(false);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The stack trace:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at com.mif.mobr0858.GUI.LoadThread.run(LoadThread.java:47)
at com.mif.mobr0858.GUI.FileChooser$2.actionPerformed(FileChooser.java:77)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at com.mif.mobr0858.GUI.WelcomeFrame$2.actionPerformed(WelcomeFrame.java:45)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Serialization:

```
try {
        //get current date
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM_HH.mm");
        String fileName;
        String fileName1;
        //select appropriate file name
        if (character instanceof Warrior) {
            fileName = "dataW_" + dateFormat.format(date).toString() + ".dat";
            fileName1 = "dataBW_" + dateFormat.format(date).toString() + ".dat";
        } else {
            fileName = "dataR_" + dateFormat.format(date).toString() + ".dat";
            fileName1 = "dataRW_" + dateFormat.format(date).toString() + ".dat";
        }
        //create file and write data
        File f = new File(fileName);
        File f1 = new File(fileName1);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        oos.writeObject(character);
        oos.close();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f1));
        oos.writeObject(frame);
        //connect to FTP
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect("*****", 21);
        boolean connOK = ftpClient.login("*****", "****");
        if (connOK) {
            MainMenu.uploadSingleFile(ftpClient, f.getAbsolutePath(), "data/" + fileName);
        }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Upload code:

```
public static boolean uploadSingleFile(FTPClient ftpClient, String localFilePath,
        String remoteFilePath) throws IOException {
    File localFile = new File(localFilePath);

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile);
    try {
            ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(ftpClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.setFileType(ftpClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            return ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFilePath, inputStream);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me solve the problem

Comment: Where is the serializing code?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the first `ObjectOutputStream.` The file is incomplete.

Comment: Note to OP - there may be other problems as well.  For example in the upload code which you haven't show us.

Comment: Such as not using binary mode for upload.

Comment: Isn't closing ObjectOutputStream in finally block enough?

Comment: That closes the second one. Not the first one. And it's after the upload. So, no.

Comment: @StephenC, I added the upload code, please, have a look

Comment: Nothing has changed. You still aren't closing the first ObjectOutputStream, so it is still incomplete. You could always try it. Hard to see why you're postiing here if you're going to ignore the answers you get.

Comment: @EJP, excuse me, I just forgot to edit the question. Still, closing the stream didn't resolve the problem. I don't think, that serialization is working wrong, as I tried downloading the file from FTP and reading it from my computer and everything went fine.